# How to configure all the special IMAP folders in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007, imap

Using different versions of Outlook with an IMAP mail account I have found how to configure Outlook 2007 to use particular folder for sent mail (but not any more). I have also found how to specify the deleted mail folder in Outlook 2010 (but not in 2007). But I'd like to choose specific sent, junk, deleted and draft mail folders. Is there a way? Perhaps a hack/patch of a sort if there is no standard way?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2007 does not support this.

[Microsoft Community thread, with moderator response.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-outlook/move-imap-deleted-items-to-deletedtrash-folder/92d2b748-3d76-48b7-957e-211b8df7d0c0)

Answer (score 1):

Create a rule that suits the requirements, and a folder to move it to.
I created a "Ham radio" folder and a rule that moves mail matching specified conditions to the folder, pops-up a notification, and rings a bell when applicable mail comes in. Same with unasked mail. Rule sends it straight to 'deleted items' folder.